# filter noisy angle signal

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter

I'm receiving a angle signal with values in the range [-180..180]

Now I want to smooth that signal over time. I'm already using [1€ filter](https://cristal.univ-lille.fr/%7Ecasiez/1euro/) quite successfully on some of the other values I need to smooth.

However the angle signal has this discontinuity when jumping from -180 to 180 and vice versa. How can I prevent any filter from failing at that critical transition.

Just as example. Moving average would fail:

```
oldAngle = 179
currentAngle = -179

movingAvg = 0.9 * oldAngle + 0.1 * currentAngle
```

would give me some bad result.

Comment: I know I've answered almost this exact question before, and I'm almost sure it's on this stackexchange.  But I can't find it!

Comment: @TimWescott Well, now the next time someone asks it, you'll have twice the chance of finding your previous answer! :)

Answer (score 4):

The difference equation you're using for your lowpass is
$$x_n = (1 - \alpha) x_{n-1} + \alpha u_n \tag 1,$$
where $\alpha$ is your "forgetting factor", $u_n$ is your input, and $x_n$ is your lowpass filtered version.

This works great for numbers of infinite extent (as you have found).  To get where you want to go with angles, recast (1) as
$$x_n = x_{n-1} + \alpha \left(u_n - x_{n - 1} \right) \tag 2.$$

Note that this has identical action algebraically.  Note, too, that you've made the difference between the current input and last tick's estimate explicit.

Now cross your fingers and hope that your angular errors are never greater than 180 degrees.  If that's correct, then you can modify (2):
$$x_n = x_{n-1} + \alpha \left(\left(u_n - x_{n - 1}\right)\ \mathrm{mod_s}\ 360^\circ \right) \tag 3.$$

This works *as long as you use a special modulo operation* at $\mathrm{mod_s}$.  You want a modulo operation that always returns the smallest-magnitude number, even if it's negative.  So $90^\circ\ \mathrm{mod_s}\ 360 = 90$, but $270^\circ\ \mathrm{mod_s}\ 360 = -90$.

I filter angles often, and use this all the time.  It works great.

Different languages and libraries implement the modulo function differently (and some older versions of C don't specify exactly what they do; don't be surprised if this isn't the case in other languages as well).  So it's up to you to get it right.  In Python, and in C/C++ with integers, I *think* this works:

```
result = (x + 180) % 360 - 180;
```

**But you should use that as a starting point and figure it out from there**.

Answer (score 1):

Tim's answer is great, but I'll give another option.

Try turning the angles, $\theta_n$ into a complex number:

$$
y_n = \cos(\theta_n) + j \sin(\theta_n)
$$

and then applying the smoothing filter to that:
$$
z_n = (1-\alpha) z_{n-1} + \alpha y_n 
$$
and then find the angle of $z_n$:

$$
x_n = \arg(z_n)
$$

Comment: good idea, but it seems that results are quite jittery for me. Maybe it's because I'm  smoothing the real and imaginary part of my angle independently using two 1€ filter. I'll post an update once I get a stable filtering with this approach

Answer (score 0):

You can use [numpy.unwrap](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unwrap.html) to remove discontinuities in angular signals. You might need to adjust the bounds to [0, 359] by adding a temporary offset and set `period=360`. Once the signal is unwrapped, perform your filter and rewrap it if needed using something similar to

`wrapped_phases = (unwrapped_phases + 180) % (360) - 180`.

Comment: That works well for batch filtering, but not for real-time filtering.